# Is PostgreSQL multi-row insertion all or nothing?

Tags: database, postgresql, insert, transactions, atomic

I would like to know if a PostgreSQL multi-row `INSERT` is safe (all data is inserted or no data is inserted in case of system/database failure). Example of query:

```
INSERT INTO "tests" ("name") VALUES ('1'), ('2')
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your own answer (now deleted) is mis-interpreting things. A single `INSERT` statement is ***always atomic***. Your example `INSERT` with two rows is **all or nothing** - both rows are inserted or none.

Whether autocommit is enabled or not is up to your client.

In **psql** autocommit is enabled by default. All that means is that each *statement* runs as a transaction of its own, unless you wrap (any number of) statements into an explicit transaction wrapper. So this is "all or nothing":

```
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('1'), ('2');
```

Just like this:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('2');
COMMIT;
```

But not this:

```
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('2');
```

In **pgAdmin** everything you send from the query window at once is wrapped into a transaction by default.